# IntelliJ shortcut previous/next caret position windows

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Just read blog http://hadihariri.com/2014/06/24/no-tabs-in-intellij-idea/
and there is mentioned

> If you want to move back and forth between where you are and where you
>   just were: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to go back and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to go forward. Of course, if
>   your current and previous position is in different files, it will also
>   go back and forth between them.

I'm a Windows user and wish to use that function but never found this setting

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to this reference card from Jetbrains the default back/forward navigation shortcut in the Windows keymap is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrows:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Comment: This works. However - with tabs disabled - this shortcut works only for going backward. Moving forward is possible only in file (when tabs enabled it starts working as intended) - or maybe this is PyCharm specyfic what I'm currently on.

Comment: ctrl + alt + left/right reorients the screen in windows 8

Comment: Indeed - you need to disable this function in Windows to enjoy default shortcut from Intellj

Comment: Here is a cross link to how to [fix windows screen orientation](http://superuser.com/questions/279756/how-to-disable-the-screen-orientation-hotkeys-in-windows-xp) setting.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux (e.g. Debian Bookworm), the keymap shortcut is dependent on the desktop you running. E.g. I am using GNOME, so for me, to Navigate back/forward, its **ALT-SHIFT-LEFT/RIGHT**

[image]

(***Intellij IDEA 2023.1.5 (Community Edition)***)